# Strange behaviour on writing to db while using service broker

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, service-broker

I am testing both service broker external activator and polling based client on behalf of process speed performances of each.

For external activator, I have built a command line application which is being notified when any change occur some table and writes to the same db. Code inside exe looks like as follows

```
 private static void ProcessRequest()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ServiceConstant.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            do
            {
                using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    //Get a message from the queue
                    byte[] message = QueueProcessorUtil.GetMessage(ServiceConstant.QueueName, connection, tran, ServiceConstant.WaitforTimeout);
                    if (message != null)
                    {
                        MessageReceiving = true;
                        try
                        {
                            //Write it to the db
                            ProcessMessage(message);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.Write("Fail: " + ex);
                        }
                        tran.Commit();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tran.Commit();
                        MessageReceiving = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (MessageReceiving);
        }
    }
```

When I insert 20 messages to the queue, total duration of insertion of all the messages is approx *10ms*

[image]

When I extract the `ProcessMessage` function above which writes the messages to the db to an another separate console application and then call this function 20 times as follows, this time it takes approx *50ms*

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                string message = "mm";
                ProcessMessaage(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

`ProcessMessage` function

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO [Workflow].[dbo].[TestOrderLog]([OrderId],[RecordTime]) 
                        VALUES (@orderId, GETDATE()) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConnection"].ToString()))
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderId", 1);
                    try
                    {
                        var result = com.ExecuteScalar();
                        var id = (result != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(result) : 0;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
```

I don't understand and am surprised although there are costly processing blocks (query a message) inside the loop of external activator code, it takes faster to write db than pure loop in console app code.

Why would pure insertion in a loop be slower than insertion inside the external activator exe instance's code?

**Side note**, in EAService.config file, `<Concurrency min="1" max="1" />`

Comment: Ok please explain what you are asking. You are saying  it takes faster to write db than pure loop in console app code? So writing to a DB is faster than using a console app? Not sure what the question is here.

Comment: @Namphibian actually I wrote everything, external activator fires the exe, the loop inside this code (`ProcessRequest` function) however, somehow insert to db faster than the the console app.  If you inspect the intervals, on each millisecond 4 to 8 records inserted in the first one, on the other hand it takes 3 ms to insert only one record for the second case. How on earth this happens? The loop in the first code above has also query to database first place as well.

Comment: Read about O Notation and try work out which one has a lower O factor.

Comment: As I know, the lesser the number of steps, the faster the algorithm, so, second one should be the faster, but let me calc the O factor and see.

Comment: Hold on you use a transaction in first one but not second?

Comment: Yes, but in the first one, inside ProcessRequest function I open a new connection without using the outer transaction. Yet I have tested the second code with using a transaction either for each connection in loop or one transaction out of the loop that each insert statement sticks to, however all approx same result, slower than the first.. I couldn't even reach to the first result table (image 1)

Comment: Yes but when batch commiting there is less transactions to be managed. All records has one transaction vs each record having a transaction itself.

Comment: So this is supporting the weirdness :) As you see, inside first one separate transaction is being created for each insert, and this transaction is not passed to ProcessMessage, this function opens its connection itself, despite all, it is faster. I tried the second one with a clean, seperate transaction out of the loop for each insert statement as I said, but it is still slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an absurd mistake of mine, first one is compiled and deployed running code
and the second one is running with debugger inside visual studio, so the intervals became normal running without debugger.

Comment: Yip that would be the problem.

Comment: @Namphibian Yes, I was about to lose my mind, thanks for your efforts btw :)